# StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AddBidComponent -> Date]:

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular6, bootstrap-datepicker

While using date picker in angular 6 I am getting this error

> **ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AddBidComponent -> Date]:
>
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AddBidComponent -> Date]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Date!** Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AddBidComponent -> Date]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AddBidComponent -> Date]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Date!

I have already added date class in provider

I am attaching my module class also please review it

```
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    GooglePlaceModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({apiKey: 'api-key'}),
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()
  ], 

  declarations: [
    SingleProjectComponent,
    AddBidComponent
  ],

  providers: [
    GoogleMapsAPIWrapper,
    GoogleMapService,
    BsDatepickerModule
  ]
})

export class SingleProjectModule { }
```

Please help me to resolve this error

Comment: You don't need to provide `Date` as DI.  Date will be available available OOTB.

Comment: @SunilSingh can you please elaborate?

Comment: And afer removing from provider again I am getting same error